# Can't create Kendo GanttChart: undefined is not a function, although GanttDataSource creates successfully

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, mean.io

I'm try to use [kendo gantt chart](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt) in mean.io project.
And faced with trouble that chart doesn't work - `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. [Gantt data source](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/ganttdatasource) creates correctly

Version of kendo is 2014.3.1119

Kendo javascript, css and other resources are includes now in main html file, `default.html`

When i move kendo includings in html file with chart definition, bug goes away. 
Gantt chart creates with datasource and works correctly except localization

html includes:

```
<!-- including css -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css' />
<!-- including javascript -->
<script src='kendo/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js'></script>
<script src="kendo/js/cultures/kendo.culture.ru-RU.min.js"></script>
<!-- setting locale -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        kendo.culture('ru-RU');
</script>
```

javascript:

```
var tasksDataSource = new kendo.data.GanttDataSource({...}); // works always
var gantt = $('#gantt').kendoGantt({
    dataSource: tasksDataSource,...}); // works only if includes are in same file
```

How can i fix these bugs? Am i doing something wrong or they are kendo's bugs?

Full bug text:

> !
>           TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at  (/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:2620), :97:28)
>           m.Callbacks.j (bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:27244)
>       at Object.m.Callbacks.k.add [as done] (bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:27553)
>           m.fn.ready (bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:29659)
>       at eval (eval at  (bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:2620), :3:15)
>           eval (native)
>       at bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:2620
>           Function.m.extend.globalEval (bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:2631)
>       at m.fn.extend.domManip (bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:3:23046)
>           m.fn.extend.append (bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:3:20507) 
>         anonymous function)
>       $get
>       compositeLinkFn 
>       updateView
>         anonymous function)
>       $get.Scope.$broadcast
>         state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition
>       deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback
>         anonymous function)
>       $get.Scope.$eval
>         get.Scope.$digest 
>       $get.Scope.$apply
>       completeRequest 
>         .onreadystatechange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, try [angular-gantt-chart](https://github.com/narensulegai/angular-gantt) via `bower install angular-gantt-chart --save`

or [taitems/jQuery.Gantt](https://github.com/taitems/jQuery.Gantt) via `bower install jquery-gantt --save`

Comment: Thanks, probably i will do so - change kendo component to another